# how can i get individual data variables into another page after building a function in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

how can i get individual data variables into another page after building a function that displays them all

This is the calling of the function which i will be using php for later to query list of them from the database.

```
      buildOrderItem('images/shoe.jpg', "Men's Italian Shoe", 150.00),
      buildOrderItem('images/suit.jpg', 'FloTextile Suit', 450.00),
      buildOrderItem('images/heels.jpg', "Women's Heel", 200.00),
```

and this is the function

```
Container buildOrderItem(imagelink, productName, price) {
    return Container(
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => new ProductPage()));
        },
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 10, bottom: 10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Image.asset(
                  imagelink,
                  width: 250,
                  height: 150,
                  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: Text(
                        productName,
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: Text(
                        'N' + price.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.deepOrange),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

from the ontap, how can i pass the data variables `(imagelink, productName, price)` from the particular product i click into the next screen...

```
onTap:(){
          Navigator.push(
            context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => new ProductPage()));
            },
```

i tried sending the variables as parameters into the routes but I'm receiving null.

kindly help, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
buildOrderItem(
                        'assets/images/researcher.png',
                        "mans's Heel",
                        200.00,
                        () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            new MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  ProductPage('mans\'s Heel'),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
```

then on this section do this

```
Widget buildOrderItem(imagelink, productName, price, Function ontap) {
  return Container(
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: ontap,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 10, bottom: 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Image.asset(
                imagelink,
                width: 250,
                height: 150,
                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: Text(
                      productName,
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: Text(
                      'N' + price.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.deepOrange),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Errors with this ```buildOrderItem('images/shoe.jpg', "Men's Italian Shoe", 150.00,(){
          Navigator.push(
            context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => new ProductPage(imagelink, productName, price)));

}),```

Comment: Have edited my answer after testing it, on my side no errors from it.The current one will help you out

Comment: Oh great, it's working, but how to i call it from the second page... and i also want to send it with imagelink, productName, price,

Comment: Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            new MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  ProductPage('assets/images/researcher.png','mans\'s Heel',200.00),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
then generate contructor on productpage

Answer (score 2):

Just create constructor for your `ProductPage` and pass your variables to there

```
class ProductPage extends StatelessWidget { /* Or StatefulWidget and then in the State use these variable like widget.someVariable*/
  ProductPage({
      required this.someVariable,
      required this.someVariable2,
      required this.someVariable3,
      Key? key,
    }) : super(key: key);


  final String someVariable;
  final String someVariable2;
  final double someVariable3;
 
  //...
}
```

To pass these variables:

```
//...

ProductPage(
    someVariable: 'Some value',
    someVariable2: 'Some value',
    someVariable3: 101.12,
)

//...
```

You should also create a class `Product` that will contain these variables (better with final keyword) and then pass this class

If you want to have your product in a few pages, you should use [InheritedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) or [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package (it actually uses InheritedWidget and it is just easyer and more convinient)

Comment: How can i do this? thanks? I'm a bit new to this... Started recently.

Comment: i get some error with this  ``` ProductPage({
      required this.someVariable,
      required this.someVariable2,
      required this.someVariable3,
      Key? key,
    }) : super(key: key);```

Comment: Also, it sending null when i called with ```widget.someVariable;```